# UV Seam Problem exporting FBX from Blender to Maya

Tags: modeling, uv, export, .fbx, seams

I have been having this major issue exporting a fountain mesh from Blender to Maya through FBX. During import into Maya random Seams/Cuts appear in the mesh which were not made in the original Blender mesh. Reducing excess data on the mesh (such as excess edge bevel weights after the bevel modifier was applied) helped slightly but did not overall solve the issue.

Here is the Blender mesh's original UV layout, I exported this mesh without any seams remaining on the mesh yet the random seams/cuts in Maya appeared.

[image]

Attached below is a section the UV Layout from the export.

Left image is 3DS Max UV shell of the mesh after import from Blender (Green line are Seams/Cuts). Right image is Maya's UV shell of the mesh after import from Blender (Thicker white lines are Seams/Cuts)

[image: Left image is 3DS Max UV shell of the mesh after import from Blender (Green line are Seams/Cuts). Right image is Maya's UV shell of the mesh after import from Blender (Thicker white lines are Seams/Cuts).]

Does anyone know a way to export a mesh (as an FBX) from Blender that will preserve/not generate random seams/cuts upon import into Maya?